# Zoom map between two points, Using Mapzen Android SDK

Tags: android, mapzen, tangram

Using Mapzen Android sdk, I have drawn a route between two points using latitude and longitude on map with `mapData.addPolyline(markers, props);` method.

Now i want to zoom map between these two points.

**Zooming to single point can be done by below method :**

```
public void goToLandmark(Landmark landmark) {

    if (map == null) {
        return;
    }

    int duration = 2000; // Milliseconds

    // We use the position, zoom, tilt, and rotation of the Landmark to move the camera over time.
    // Different types of "easing" are available to make the transition smoother or sharper.
    map.setPositionEased(landmark.position, duration, MapController.EaseType.CUBIC);
    map.setZoomEased(landmark.zoom, duration, MapController.EaseType.LINEAR);
    map.setTiltEased(landmark.tilt, duration, MapController.EaseType.CUBIC);
    map.setRotationEased(landmark.rotation, duration, MapController.EaseType.CUBIC);
}
```

Please guide me, Thank you in advance.

Comment: these points can be any where on map, just like start and end point of route

Comment: There is a map of world on my screen, i enter two place start point and destination, I want map should be zoom to these two location.

Comment: so read `CameraUpdateFactory` official documentation

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Do you want the map to zoom in so both points are on the edges of the screen? Or do you want to animate the map along the route between the two points?

Comment: Exactly, I want the map to zoom in so both points are on the edges of the screen.

Comment: Want to create a bounding box between these two points